# C# COM Server to C# COM Client using CoCreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com

I need to create a C# COM server, and a C# COM Client, and communicate between the two using CoCreateInstance.

This is so that the client can be 64 bit, and the server 32 bit, using the 'DllSurrogate' method described in [Hosting a .NET DLL as an Out-Of-Process COM Server (EXE)](https://dzone.com/articles/hosting-net-dll-out-process).

However, at the moment I have both in 32 bit, but am struggling to get it working.

There are online samples to create a C# COM server: [COM Interop Part 2: C# Server Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738(v=vs.71).aspx)

And to create a C# COM client: [COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx)

But I haven't found an example that does both.
My attempts so far have failed, and I suspect that the Microsoft COM server used for the C# COM client example includes extra specification not in the C# COM server sample.

My attempts so far are below.
The C# client call to CoCreateInstance is apparently successful, but the object returned seems empty (not null), and the attempt to cast it to the interface fails.

Can anyone spot the problem, or provide a fully joined up example?

This is my server code:

```
// AntCsServer.cs
// Project settings:
    // compile as a library
    // Select 'Make assembly COM Visible'
    // Select 'Register for COM Interop'

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace AntCsServer
{
    // Since the .NET Framework interface and coclass have to behave as 
    // COM objects, we have to give them guids.
    [Guid("555E2D2B-EE00-47AA-AB2B-39F953F6B339")]
    public interface IManagedInterface
    {
        int PrintHi(string name);
    }

    [Guid("0190D7A6-8D8D-4031-810A-627BA3EE68A6")]
    public class InterfaceImplementation : IManagedInterface
    {
        public int PrintHi(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", name);
            return 33;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my client code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComClient
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string ComSvrInterface_GUID = "555E2D2B-EE00-47AA-AB2B-39F953F6B339";
        public const string ComSvrClass_GUID = "0190D7A6-8D8D-4031-810A-627BA3EE68A6";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ole32Methods.CoInitialize((IntPtr)0);

            object instance1 = null;
            string sErr1;
            bool b1;
            IManagedInterface cCom = null;

            b1 = Ole32Methods.CreateComObject(ComSvrClass_GUID, ComSvrInterface_GUID, out instance1, out sErr1);

            if (b1)
            {
                cCom = instance1 as IManagedInterface;
            }

            if (cCom != null)
            {
                cCom.PrintHi("Santa Claus");
                Console.WriteLine("Should have just printed Santa Claus");
            }

        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------

    // Reproduce the interface here so we can cast to it
    [Guid("555E2D2B-EE00-47AA-AB2B-39F953F6B339")]
    public interface IManagedInterface
    {
        int PrintHi(string name);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------

    public class Ole32Methods
    {
        [DllImport("ole32.Dll")]
        static public extern uint CoCreateInstance(ref Guid clsid,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object inner,
           uint context,
           ref Guid uuid,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int CoInitialize(IntPtr pvReserved);

        // ------------------------

        public static bool CreateComObject(string sClassGuid, string sInterfaceGuid, out object instance, out string sErr)
        {
            const uint CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER = 1;
            //const uint CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER = 4;

            // CLSID of the COM object
            Guid clsid = new Guid(sClassGuid);

            // GUID of the required interface
            //Guid IID_IUnknown = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
            Guid IID_Interface = new Guid(sInterfaceGuid);

            instance = null;

            uint hResult = Ole32Methods.CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, null,
                           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref IID_Interface, out instance);


            // Some error codes. See 'winerror.h for more, and use the following to convert the debug value to Hex: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm

            const uint S_OK = 0x00000000;       //Operation successful
            const uint E_NOTIMPL = 0x80004001;       //Not implemented
            const uint E_NOINTERFACE = 0x80004002;       //No such interface supported
            const uint E_POINTER = 0x80004003;       //Pointer that is not valid
            const uint E_ABORT = 0x80004004;       //Operation aborted
            const uint E_FAIL = 0x80004005;       //Unspecified failure
            const uint E_UNEXPECTED = 0x8000FFFF;       //Unexpected failure
            const uint E_ACCESSDENIED = 0x80070005;       //General access denied error
            const uint E_HANDLE = 0x80070006;       //Handle that is not valid
            const uint E_OUTOFMEMORY = 0x8007000E;       //Failed to allocate necessary memory
            const uint E_INVALIDARG = 0x80070057;       //One or more arguments are not valid

            const uint E_CLASSNOTREG = 0x80040154;      // Class not registered

            sErr = "";
            switch (hResult)
            {
                case S_OK:
                    sErr = "";
                    break;
                case E_NOTIMPL:
                    sErr = "E_NOTIMPL: Not implemented";
                    break;
                case E_NOINTERFACE:
                    sErr = "E_NOINTERFACE: No such interface supported";
                    break;
                case E_POINTER:
                    sErr = "E_POINTER: Pointer that is not valid";
                    break;
                case E_ABORT:
                    sErr = "E_ABORT: Operation aborted";
                    break;
                case E_FAIL:
                    sErr = "E_FAIL: Unspecified failure";
                    break;
                case E_UNEXPECTED:
                    sErr = "E_UNEXPECTED: Unexpected failure";
                    break;
                case E_ACCESSDENIED:
                    sErr = "E_ACCESSDENIED: General access denied error";
                    break;
                case E_HANDLE:
                    sErr = "E_HANDLE: Handle that is not valid";
                    break;
                case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
                    sErr = "E_OUTOFMEMORY: Failed to allocate necessary memory";
                    break;
                case E_INVALIDARG:
                    sErr = "E_INVALIDARG: One or more arguments are not valid";
                    break;

                case E_CLASSNOTREG:
                    sErr = "E_CLASSNOTREG: Class not registered";
                    break;
            }

            return hResult == 0;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C++? Please don't spam tags.

Comment: Most COM stuff is done by C++ experts, so I thought someone from that group might know more about what goes on under the hood in this area.

Comment: It's a strange way to instantiate COM instant from the C# using the CoCreateInstance. I think it is much easier to use the Activator class.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the first link you posted, and everything worked fine the very first try. I recommend you follow the instructions a little more carefully. (Also, don't initialize COM yourself -- .NET calls CoInitialize for you.)

Comment: Also, [use the first `CoCreateInstance` definition from here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32.cocreateinstance) instead of the one you have. .NET has built-in support for handling `HRESULT` values returned from p/invoked methods. You can literally replace your entire `Ole32Methods` class with a single p/invoke method (and [the corresponding `CLSCTX` enum](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/CLSCTX.html)).

Comment: @AntWaters That is abusing the tags. Most C++ stuff is done by assembly experts, so should we be adding the assembly tag to C++ questions? I think not. Just add the tags that are relevant to the question.

Comment: @Michael When you say "the first link", do you mean the 'DllSurrogate' stuff?  I haven't got that far yet, so that is not the issue at the moment.  However, if you mean you created a COM server in C#, and consumed it in a C# client using 'CoCreateInstance', can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?  I did try the alternative version of 'CoCreateInstance' but got the same behaviour.

Comment: Check your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file for the `ComVisible` attribute. Is it `true`? Register the assembly by hand. Any apparent issues? Export the tlb by hand. Any apparent issues?

Comment: @Michael, yes the COM server is set to COM visible.  In fact, I have now been able to connect the 32-bit C# COM server to a 64 bit C++/CLI client dll, so it seems to be something to do with C#.  The C++ version uses 'CoCreateInstance' but imports the tlb instead of defining the interfaces directly in the client.  I thought that wasn't going to work for 64 bit but it seems to.  It would be nice to be able to do everything in C# though...

Comment: Are you specifically compiling your C# COM server to target 32-bit platforms, or are you targeting "AnyCPU"? Is your COM server registered in the 32-bit or 64-bit registry?

Comment: I am specifically compiling my C# COM server with x86 (32 bit), and I believe it is registered in the 32 bit sections.

Comment: I still don't see any issue. It might help if we could see your entire workflow. Consider posting your AssemblyInfo.cs file, the command lines (and outputs) that you are using for registration (etc), and a simplified form of the client exe code.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the comments. The code above is the full code for this 32-bit test.  In the C# COm server properties I have selected 'Make Assembly COM visible' and 'Regsiter for COM Interop', so the registration is done as it is built. In debugging the C# client I can see that the cast to the interface fails. For clarity, have you successfully used the code above, or have you just been giving me general suggestions?

Comment: General suggestions. I have it working fine with the COM server code that you have above. In order to do so, I had to either put the DLL in the GAC (as per the article you reference) or copy it into the same folder as my test code.

Comment: I tried the GAC, but it was part of a confused process so I will try again at some point.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you still at the point where you're loading your COM server in-proc? If so, I think I know the problem. Check the type of the object returned from `CoCreateInstance`. Is it `System.__ComObject`? I bet it's not. The CLR is loading your assembly in-proc, so it loads it using standard assembly loading. The resulting object you get from `CoCreateInstance` is a literal `AntCsServer.InterfaceImplementation` class, which implements the interface in the server DLL, not the interface in your client EXE.

Comment: Confirmed this. In my client EXE, if I try to cast the CoCreateInstance'd object to an interface defined in my client EXE, it fails. If I reference the COM server DLL explicitly and cast the object to the DLL's interface, it works fine.

Comment: @Michael Gunter I think you are right.  When I switch to out of process I can get it to work without using C++.  So it was bad luck that what I thought was the easiest test first (32-bit to 32-bit in-process) turns out to be the one that doesn't work!  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @AntWaters : I've formulated this discussion into an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading your COM server in-process. This causes the CLR to load your assembly in-proc, so it loads it using standard assembly loading. The resulting object you get from `CoCreateInstance` is a literal `AntCsServer.InterfaceImplementation` class, which implements the interface in the server DLL, not the interface in your client EXE.

This can be confirmed by checking the type of the object you get back from `CoCreateInstance`. If it's a `System.__ComObject`, you are getting a real COM object (a proxy object for the .NET object). If not, then the problem is as I described -- you are actually getting an instance of the assembly's type.